# When the endomorphism ring of an abelian group is generated by automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Given an abelian group $M$. First I'd like to know if $\text{End}(M)$ is generated by $\text{Aut}(M)$ (as ring, or equivalently, as additive group). Second I'd like to know if it doesn't hold generally, then what condition will guarantee it.

I guess it holds at least when $M/\text{Tor}(M)$ is a free abelian group. And under this constraint, it suffices to consider abelian $p$-groups and free groups. I succeeded to prove that it always holds for free abelian groups of finite rank. But I cannot prove the case of abelian $p$-groups and general free abelian groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true for $M=C_2\times C_4$.

Let $x$ and $y$ be generators of the two factors. Then every endomorphism $\varphi$ is of the form
$$\begin{align}
\varphi(x)&=ax+2by\\
\varphi(y)&=cx+dy
\end{align}$$
for integers $a,b,c$ determined$\pmod{2}$ and $d$ determined$\pmod{4}$. But if $\varphi$ is an automorphism then $\varphi(y)$ has order $4$, and so $d$ is odd. But then $a$ is also odd, or else $\varphi(x)=2by$ is a multiple of $\varphi(y)$.

So for all automorphisms, and hence all endomorphisms that are sums of automorphisms, $a+d$ must be odd. So in particular the projection onto either factor is not in the subgroup of $\operatorname{End}(M)$ generated by $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$.

But this example seems very special to $p=2$

**EDIT:** There seems to be quite a lot of literature on this problem going back to the 1950s. See for example [this 2006 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305004382) by C. Meehan, especially the introduction and references. Some things that seems to be known: free abelian groups of arbitrary rank have this property (in fact, every endomorphism is the sum of at most two automorphisms), and finite abelian $p$-groups for $p>2$ have the property. It doesn't seem to be true for abelian $p$-groups in general, even when $p>2$, but there is a property ("total projectivity") that implies it for $p>2$.

Comment: An unexpected example... Furthermore I found that the same argument applies to all the group of form $C_{2^a}\times C_{2^b}\times N$, where $a\neq b\in\mathbb N^+$ and $N$ a finite $2$-group such that no $a$ and $b$ doesn't occur in its set of elementary factors...